# Yellow marks on the map in SW Battlefront II

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

There are different types of marks on the map in SW Battlefront II.
Enemies are displayed as red points. But my teammates are shown either with blue marks or yellow ones. What does yellow mark mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blue dots on the minimap are your teammates, either real or AI. Yellow dots on the minimap are your current Squadmates. In the lower left corner of your HUD, your Squad is listed with you and up to 3 teammates. Similarly, Squadmates can also show up green if they are your friend on Origin/console of choice.

Comment: They are blue sometimes

Comment: Amending my answer.